# Spring Boot Configuration Validation Dry Run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

im currently developing an application using Spring Boot (2.2.1.RELEASE), Spring Config and Spring Validation.

I got a few issues:

**(a)** the application itself has to start up, even if the business logic may not be runnable due to misconfiguration

**(b)** the application should be able to validate a configuration without reconfiguring the application. E.g. a rest endpoint which only validates a configuration.properties / configuration.yml

As far as I have seen by now, spring does not offer any standards for those issues. Does anyone have any advice / best practices to achieve those goals?

The application is being entirely configured via @ConfigurationProperties e.g.

```
  @ConfigurationProperties("application.credentials")
  public static class Instance {
    private final String username;
    private final CharSequence password;
    private final URI baseUrl;

    @ConstructorBinding
    public Instance(
        String username,
        CharSequence password,
        URI baseUrl) {
      this.username = username;
      this.password = password;
      this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
      return username;
    }

    public CharSequence getPassword() {
      return password;
    }

    public URI getBaseUrl() {
      return baseUrl;
    }
  }
```

Best

Comment: There is an open enhancement request, but this is not trivial to do.

Comment: Could you provide a link?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10030